# Wordpress Zip Attachments Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i am using Car Dealer wordpress theme. i want when someone open any car stock

page there is cars photos . i want there is button Download All pic zip
in theme the car page is single-car.php

i have installed a plugin Zip Attachments Version 1.6 | By Ricard Torres
PLUGIN:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/zip-attachments/

There are two coded i am using but its not working plugin says only put code

thats it but when i put code download button show and when i click download

start and save in computer with .zip format but its emptry no picture in zip

folder 0kb

```
<?=function_exists('za_show_button') ? za_show_button("Download") : ''?>
```

Shortcode

```
[za_show_download_button text="Download the file"]
```

i dont understand how its work. you can say this plugin work for wordpress

posts if there is gallery it will download all picture of single post in zip.

car theme is:
http://cardealer.webtemplatemasters.com/car/lexus-lfa-2014/

how can i use Zip Attachments plugin in this theme ? i know basic and i would

like its done by plugin no need programing much.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use this parameter you should insert an echo.

```
echo do_shortcode ('[za_show_download_button text = "Download the file"]');
```